# get the contents of a CKEditor within an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following code to display a CKEditor at http://www.wilsea.com/iframe. I can get and set the data within the html document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

   <script type="text/javaScript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
   <script src="http://www.wilsea.com/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
        <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor2
        </textarea>
   <div id="someID">Hello world!</div>
   <script>
           function myFunction() {
           var html = 'this is my new text from function1 ';
           alert('function 1 test121');
           CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(html);
           }

           function myFunction2() {
           var editorData = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
           alert('new data' + editorData);
           }
           CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
   </script>
   <p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Set Data</button>
   <button onclick="myFunction2()">Get Data</button>
   <p id="demo"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

I followed this answer here: http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/

So I added:

```
<div id="someID">Hello world!</div>.
```

I have uploaded the app to www.wilsea.com/iframe so there should be no cross domain issues.

The button code is:

```
var HTML1 =  $('#iFrame1').contents().find('#someID').html();
alert(HTML1);


var HTML1 =  $('#iFrame1').contents().find('#editor1').html();
alert(HTML1);
```

I have used the developer tools in Chrome and I see that 'id someID' exits so what part of this am I not understanding here?

My goal is to be able to:

1. Populate the html content of the CKEditor from my database.
2. Allow the client to edit / add images etc.
3. Save the html content of the CKEditor to my database.

Comment: if you check your web page something is changing your Iframe id like:iframe_wwbdbxwqq5ctcgz50ko1eqgfk4szyss94io3 so you'll never be able to get the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from here:

[https://getsatisfaction.com/application_craft/topics/accessing_an_iframe?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_reply&utm_content=reply_button&reply[id]=14399739#reply_14399739](https://getsatisfaction.com/application_craft/topics/accessing_an_iframe?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_reply&utm_content=reply_button&reply%5bid%5d=14399739#reply_14399739)

The key is that the DOM element id is not the AC widget name. But you can get and use the DOM id fairly easily with the following ('contextMenu' is the AC name of an iFrame widget in this example)

```
contextMenuId = 'iframe_' + app.w('contextMenu').base()[0].id; 

document.getElementById(contextMenuId).contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('cke_wysiwyg_frame')[0].contentDocument.body.innerHTML
```

It maybe not relevant to everyone as it is specific to application craft but the thought process may help others.

MRWarby

Comment: External sites can/do change. Always best to state what the answer was here, with a link to the external site as a reference. That way future readers can always see what you did